# How to get the amount of the specified random number in Java FOR LOOP

Tags: java, loops, random

I would like to ask how to get the amount of the specified number.
For example, I want to see the amount of the number 1234 which has been generated in the random generator. I would like it to print out the amount of the specified number which has been generated.

Merry Christmas.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: use if condition and increment operator

Comment: What do you mean by amount? Like the number of characters or just print out the number?

Comment: What do you mean by amount of a number?

Comment: What does that even mean, "the amount of the specified number"?

Comment: The amount of 1234 which has been generated in the random generator

Comment: @KyleT hi, it's something like I generated 9999 number and I want to know the amount of my favorite number 1234 has been generated.

Comment: @Lee Oh I see you want to count how many times that number has appeared in the loop?

Comment: I believe the translation is "the number of times that the number '1234' has been generated after a several calls to `rand()`"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to count the number of times a given random number was generated, and given an `int` value `MAX` with the maximum random number possible and an `int` `COUNT` for the number of random values to generate, you might create an array of `counts` and then print it. Something like

```
int COUNT = 1000;
int MAX = 100;
Random rand = new Random();
int[] counts = new int[MAX]; // <-- 0, MAX all initialized at 0.
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
  counts[rand.nextInt(MAX)]++; // <-- add one at a random index between 
                               //     0 (inclusive) and MAX (exclusive).
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and Merry Christmas. Gonna try t out. Thanks buddy. :D

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer that I wanted. I want Java to tell me how many '1234' has appear during the random generation.

Comment: @Lee 1234 is more then 100, so 0. Change `MAX` to `2000` and `COUNT` to `100000`. And the count of "1234" is in `counts[1234]`.

Comment: Hi, it appears [2,45,6,2,32,12,64,23] instead of giving me the amount of the number, or is there a way to put my specified number in any place so, Java knows what it want to find for me... or something else. Sorry if I disturd you again. Thanks for replying. :D

Comment: That's 2 zeros, 45 ones, 6 twos, etc. Remove the last line and use `System.out.println(counts[1234]);` after making the other changes.